# numpy vectorized way to change multiple rows of array(rows can be repeated)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, svm

I run into this problem when implementing the vectorized svm gradient for cs231n assignment1.
here is an example:

```
ary = np.array([[1,-9,0],
                [1,2,3],
                [0,0,0]])
ary[[0,1]] += np.ones((2,2),dtype='int')
```

and it outputs:

```
array([[ 2, -8,  1],
      [ 2,  3,  4],
      [ 0,  0,  0]])
```

everything is fine until rows is not unique:

```
ary[[0,1,1]] += np.ones((3,3),dtype='int')
```

although it didn't throw an error,the output was really strange:

```
array([[ 2, -8,  1],
       [ 2,  3,  4],
       [ 0,  0,  0]])
```

and I expect the second row should be [3,4,5] rather than [2,3,4],
the naive way I used to solve this problem is using a for loop like this:

```
ary = np.array([[ 2, -8,  1],
                [ 2,  3,  4],
                [ 0,  0,  0]])
# the rows I want to change
rows = [0,1,2,1,0,1]
# the change matrix
change = np.random.randn((6,3))
for i,row in enumerate(rows):
  ary[row] += change[i]
```

so I really don't know how to vectorize this for loop, is there a better way to do this in NumPy?
and why it's wrong to do something like this?:

```
ary[rows] += change
```

In case anyone is curious why I want to do so, here is my implementation of svm_loss_vectorized function, I need to compute the gradients of weights based on labels y:

```
def svm_loss_vectorized(W, X, y, reg):
    """
    Structured SVM loss function, vectorized implementation.

    Inputs and outputs are the same as svm_loss_naive.
    """
    loss = 0.0
    dW = np.zeros(W.shape) # initialize the gradient as zero

    # transpose X and W
    # D means input dimensions, N means number of train example
    # C means number of classes
    # X.shape will be (D,N)
    # W.shape will be (C,D)
    X = X.T
    W = W.T
    dW = dW.T
    num_train = X.shape[1]
    # transpose W_y shape to (D,N) 
    W_y = W[y].T
    S_y = np.sum(W_y*X ,axis=0)
    margins =  np.dot(W,X) + 1 - S_y
    mask = np.array(margins>0)

    # get the impact of num_train examples made on W's gradient
    # that is,only when the mask is positive 
    # the train example has impact on W's gradient
    dW_j = np.dot(mask, X.T)
    dW +=  dW_j
    mul_mask = np.sum(mask, axis=0, keepdims=True).T

    # dW[y] -= mul_mask * X.T
    dW_y =  mul_mask * X.T
    for i,label in enumerate(y):
      dW[label] -= dW_y[i]

    loss = np.sum(margins*mask) - num_train
    loss /= num_train
    dW /= num_train
    # add regularization term
    loss += reg * np.sum(W*W)
    dW += reg * 2 * W
    dW = dW.T

    return loss, dW
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using built-in `np.add.at`**

The built-in is [`np.add.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) for such tasks, i,e.

```
np.add.at(ary, rows, change)
```

But, since we are working with a `2D` array, that might not be the most performant one.

**Leveraging fast `matrix-multiplication`**

As it turns out, we can leverage the very efficient `matrix-multplication` for such a case as well and given enough number of repeated rows for summation, could be really good. Here's how we can use it -

```
mask = rows == np.arange(len(ary))[:,None]
ary += mask.dot(change)
```

---

**Benchmarking**

Let's time `np.add.at` method against `matrix-multiplication` based one for bigger arrays -

```
In [681]: ary = np.random.rand(1000,1000)

In [682]: rows = np.random.randint(0,len(ary),(10000))

In [683]: change = np.random.rand(10000,1000)

In [684]: %timeit np.add.at(ary, rows, change)
1 loop, best of 3: 604 ms per loop

In [687]: def matmul_addat(ary, rows, change):
     ...:     mask = rows == np.arange(len(ary))[:,None]
     ...:     ary += mask.dot(change)

In [688]: %timeit matmul_addat(ary, rows, change)
10 loops, best of 3: 158 ms per loop
```

Comment: is add.at a new function? I have seen it twice today

Comment: @Dark Been here for ages. But just happen to be quite useful today :)

Comment: @Divakar, yeah, thank you for reminding of `ufunc.at()` !

Comment: @Divakar, thank you so much, both way worked and the matrix-multiplication way is really what  I am looking for ~

Comment: Just stumbling across this, but wondering: How is 10 loops at 158ms per loop better than 1 loop at 604ms? That's ~1,580+ms vs 604 – this would indicate `np.add.at` is clearly better.

Comment: @AndrewRobinson That's how timeit function/medthod works and it displays the avg time required to run a method. In this case, on avg `604 ms` is needed to run np.add.at vs `158 ms` for bincount. It loops more for functions that takes less time, so that the average displayed is accurate.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks.

Comment: `def matmul_addat(ary, row, change):` should be `rows`?

Comment: @Jonathan Yup, seemed like a bug. Thanks! Fixed.